# Why do I get an error by using tenary operator?

Tags: if-statement, flutter, dart

I tried to make a Text, which should only be visible, if `variable1 == "1"`, but I got an error. can anybody tell me why I get this error? Below is the code I tried. Thanks in advance!

```
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 28.0),
                child:
                Container(
                  child: variable1 == "1"
                  ?Text(
                    "Test",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add something to be returned if the condition is false with `:`

Ternary operation syntax:

`[condition] ? [do this if the condition is true] : [do this if the condition is false]`

In your case, you should return a `SizedBox` as it is more efficient.

Like this

```
Container(
    child: variable1 == "1"
           ? Text(
               "Test",
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)
             )
           : SizedBox()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you didn't add the `else` part of the ternary operator.
Check the code below: It adds an empty `Container` that is not visible if `variable1 != null`.

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 28.0),
      child: Container(
        child: variable1 == "1"
            ? Text(
                "Test",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              )
            : Container(),
      ),
    );
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add,  what if condition is wrong. You can specify after doing(:). as i specified empty text.

```
child: variable1 == "1"
                  ?Text(
                    "Test",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                  ): Text(""),
```